# "statusCode": 422 should be number in loopback 4

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have json object from angular as `{"weight": "50"}` but LoopBack 4 needs `{"weight": 50}`. How can I achieve this? I do not want to make any change in angular. Is there any settings in LoopBack 4?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

LoopBack uses the popular library [AJV](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) to validate incoming requests. It is possible to configure AJV to coerce types during validation, e.g. convert string `"50"` to a number `50` for a numeric property, see [Coercing data types](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#coercing-data-types).

To enable coercion, modify your main application file (`src/application.ts`) as follows:

Import `RestBindings` from `@loopback/rest`:

```
import {RestApplication, RestBindings} from '@loopback/rest';
```

Add the following line at the end of your application constructor:

```
this.bind(RestBindings.REQUEST_BODY_PARSER_OPTIONS).to({
  validation: {coerceTypes: true},
})
```

Please note this setup will enable coercion for all model properties and all value types. See [AJV Coercion Rules](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/COERCION.md) to better understand what will happen to different value types.

Comment: Thank yo will try this and let you know.